# How to add a spectrogram to a paper

Tags: phonetics, praat

I would like to include some examples of spectrograms in a paper I am writing. What are some of the ways to get a picture to include? I thought it might be the "draw" feature in Praat but it doesn't seem to work for spectrograms. Using a screen shot also does not seem to be the most elegant solution. Is there another way?

Comment: I don't see a big problem with screnshots; if you do them well cut-out and in a decent resolution, it usually goes pretty smooth in a paper. Since spectrograms are not as simple graphs as, e.g., oscillographs, I doubt there are tools that can replicate them nicelier than what you get in Praat directly.

Comment: It depends on your ultimate plan for the paper. Certain major publishers actually have huge problems processing EPS files, and integrating something that isn't a screen shot into Word can be challenging. My experience with Paint to Picture Window and Clipboard copy is that the result is terrible; YMMV.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need the correct Praat command: "Paint visible spectrogram...". Here is the relevant manual page: http://www.fon.hum.uva.nl/praat/manual/Intro_3_4__Printing_the_spectrogram.html